# Writing to server with github pages

Tags: github-pages

Is it possible to write to text files (or upload files or any other changing of the files) with github pages? I've heard github pages are static sites, so you can't use php on them. Is there any other programming language which allows you to write to the server with github pages, or is the idea of a static site that the file structure can't be changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or is the idea of a static site that the file structure can't be changed?

Exactly. You can't write to the server of a GitHub pages site, because there isn't really a server. (There is a file server that serves your pages, but that's not what you're looking for.)

You can write to a **different** server from your GitHub pages site. For example you could create a server using Java servlets, or PHP, or Python, or Node.js. This would **not** be hosted on GitHub Pages. Then you could do stuff like make REST calls from JavaScript on your GitHub Pages site to your server.

Of course, if you go through the trouble of creating this separate server, you can probably just host your static content on that server as well, so you wouldn't need GitHub Pages anymore.

It all depends on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking to do things like that you can upload an image which will be on the front page, and everyone could upload an image.